# Excel 2007 Pivot Table Group Multiple Sets by One Other Set

Tags: excel-2007, pivot, pivot-table

This seems like it should be easy.  I have a data set consisting of binary survey answers, "yes" and "no".  I also demographic data such as gender, "male" and "female".  I am trying to generate a single pivot table in Excel 2007 that shows the answer counts of multiple questions by a single demographic field.  I can do one at a time but when I try to do more, they seem to get nested under each other.  I have tried putting gender in the rows and the questions in the labels and vice versa to no avail.  The closet I have gotten is by putting gender in the rows and a question under that but that's it.  For the values I am simply using the count of responses.

Here is an example of what my data....

```
Gender Q1  Q2  Q3  
Female yes yes yes  
Male   yes no  yes
Male   no  no  yes
Female no  yes no
```

Here is what I want to get....

```
Gender   Q1       Q2       Q3
         yes  no  yes  no  yes  no
Female   1    1   2    0   1    1
Male     1    1   0    2   2    0
```

Any tips would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your data is not what the PivotTable needs.
You'd need to re-order the data in the following way, so that you have one column for each field you want to use in the results: Gender, Quartal, Answer (see screenshot).

Then your PivotTable will work perfectly.

For re-arranging the data you could use a VBA macro which splits the contents of one line in your original table in 3 lines.
Another way would be to use `MS Access` to re-arrange the data - you'll find a solution here: http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/accqueryjournal.htm . This might be also possible with MS Query in `MS Excel`(I have not tried it with Excel yet, but the access solution works fine).

[image]

Comment: Yes, I understand this approach and was able to solve it this way.  However, it took quite a bit of reformatting of the original data by hand which was what I was trying to avoid.  Your suggestion of using a macro would probably have helped but I would have had to start at square 1 learning about macros.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I know that it is a lot of work to re-arrange the data. Professional data analysis software like `SAS JMP` has in-built functions to rearrange data by stacking two columns into one (what you'd have needed) or splitting one column into several (the other way around). I had the same problem yesterday and found a quite simple solution based on `MS Access`, maybe it could also done with Query's in MS Excel: http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/accqueryjournal.htm p.s. you could also rate my answer if you find it helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Guess it can't be done.  I have tried several different approaches and could get none of them to work.  I ended up breaking up the data manually using the old fashioned way, cell equations.  Too bad, I thought this would be a pretty basic thing to accomplish.

Comment: it's the structure of your original data which is not suited for pivot table analysis. See my answer (you might have found it out yourself in the meantime): http://stackoverflow.com/a/13124736/772434

Answer (score -3):

If you place gender for the first row label, use the filter tool to show what you want. i.e. filter one gender out or the other.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question

Comment: please undertand the question before proposing an answer